# f5, AWS, Citrix. How do these all fit together when my focus is user access control?

Tags: security, citrix, f5

I'm struggling to find conclusive answers to my questions. I see f5 BIG-IP everywhere but I first heard of it as being able to handle user control - which is what I'm looking for. I mention BIG-IP because it seems to be linked with AWS.

I find f5 can be used with Citrix. I thought Citrix was a competitor so that's confusing.

I'm using AWS. How can I improve security to my web projects hosted on AWS with f5 or Citrix or any other tool? I just need to more securely control user access to certain applications.

Comment: hum, maybe superuser would be a better fit for this

Comment: how can i move it over?

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I work for F5. Our access control product is the BIG-IP Access Policy Manager, and is highly flexible and capable to sit in front of all kinds of applications, Citrix included.

Our product page for APM is here: https://f5.com/products/big-ip/access-policy-manager-apm and our community site has plenty of articles detailing deployment strategies: https://devcentral.f5.com/articles?tag=apm

One article highlighting a deployment of Citrix federated services behind the APM highlights the interoperability of F5 with other vendors: https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/citrix-federated-authentication-service-integration-with-apm-24489.

Comment: Does this mean APM cannot be used without BIG-IP?

Comment: BIG-IP is the platform, APM is a module on the platform. So you can license only APM if you want.

Comment: And I can use APM without having BIG-IP installed? Sorry - I'm just trying to get my head around everything.

Comment: BIG-IP APM ... BIG-IP is the platform, APM is the product. So you can license the product APM by itself, which runs on the BIG-IP platform. OR, you can license multiple products like LTM, ASM, APM, all on the BIG-IP platform. Make sense?